# S.O.S. MAGAZINE Impulse Synthesis In Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, convolution

"Chaotic dynamical systems can provide an infinite variety of timbre in terms of impulse responses. Following is a model of the MATLAB code required to produce mono Duffing IRs." [link to the article](https://www.soundonsound.com/sos/sep10/articles/matlab.htm?print=yes) I am getting the error "Function definitions are not permitted in this context."

```
 function [] = create_duffing() % the main function

 global gamma omega epsilon GAM OMEG % declaration of global variables

 gamma=0.1; omega=1; epsilon=0.25; OMEG=2; % system paramaters

 length = 16000 ; % IR length settings in samples

 [t x]=ode45(@A_duffing,0:2*pi/OMEG/50:length,[0 1]); % actual system calculation

 X = x(:,1); % retrieval of one of the variables

 XF = fft(X); % FFT

 XF = XF(1:length(XF)/2); % takes the first half of FFT

 X = real(XF).^2 + imag(XF).^2; % calculates the power spectrum

 wavwrite(X,44100,24,'filename.wav'); % writes the file

 end % closes the function

 function xdot=duffing(t,x) % the system function

 global gamma omega epsilon GAM OMEG % declaration of global variables

 xdot(1)=-gamma*x(1)+omega^2*x(2)-epsilon*x(2)^3+GAM*cos(OMEG*t); % system equation, line 1

 xdot(2)=x(1); % system equation, line 2

 xdot=xdot'; % system equation, line 3

 end % closes the function
```

Comment: Get rid of all of the `A` and `B` crap that's at the beginning of each line.

Comment: I did but still got errors running it.

Comment: I did try them individually, still error.

Comment: I tried the code you suggested, and got this error Error: File: create_duffing.m Line: 11 Column: 16
The GLOBAL or PERSISTENT declaration of "gamma" appears in a nested function, but should be in the outermost function
where it is used.

Comment: I don't understand what the code is supposed to do.  `GAM` is never initialized so this code is already broken.

Comment: I see, thanks for taking your time and trying though, appreciated.

Comment: If you remove all of the `global` declarations and make the function `duffing` nested inside `create_duffing`, it won't run because `GAM` is never initialized.  Sorry that I couldn't help any further!